# Encrypting large streams to be sent via Amazon S3

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-s3

I want to encrypt stream and then send it using Amazon S3. I'm using legacy code and have two important parameters: non-encrypted `InputStream` and its length. This is important as AmazonS3Client wants to know the length of the stream before it uploads it.

Encrypting a stream is not very difficult task:

```
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path-to-file");
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        Key key = keygen.generateKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        OutputStream encryptedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(encryptedStream, cipher);
        out.write(in.read());
        out.flush();

        byte[] bytes = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) encryptedStream).toByteArray();
        InputStream encryptedInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

However, this approach could be used for small files only as their are written to a byte array held in memory. The thing is that I'd like to encrypt big files (> 1TB). How do I do this? More specifically, I get InputStream and my job is to return encrypted InputStream that will be used by Amazon S3.

Comment: So, to summarize: You want to know the size of the encrypted file from the size of the unencrypted file..

Comment: Now, I'd like to encrypt inputstream and have in result encrypted inputstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path-to-file");
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    Key key = keygen.generateKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    try(CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(new File("path to enc file")), cipher))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }

    return new FileInputStream(new File("path to enc file"));
```

One more answer with piped streams.

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path-to-file");
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    Key key = keygen.generateKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream();
    //write data in a separate thread.
    new Thread(() -> {
        try(CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(
                pout, cipher))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (IOException  e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();

    return new PipedInputStream(pout);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the result should be InputStream, and in your solution I have OutputStream.

Comment: just open the enc file again. Ideally speaking that inputstream should not be part of this method. It should be created by that method which takes the responsibility of closing it as well.

Comment: added one more answer. this time using piped streams. what ever is written to outputstream in one thread is piped to the input stream.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: This code makes the thread hang for files above 4GB(i assume its piped streams fault). is it possible to write it utilizing buffered streams?