# Encrypting large streams( > 1 TB) efficiently

Tags: java, encryption

[Encrypting large streams to be sent via Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117639/encrypting-large-streams-to-be-sent-via-amazon-s3)

I am trying to solve the same problem and I stumbled upon a certain problem: the thread hangs at the end when > 4 GB files come into play. Also, piped streams can be really slow..

I was thinking of replacing them with buffered streams, but I only take InputStream as a parameter, and I return an encrypted InputStream. Buffered streams require underlying streams(and I lack an OutputStream). So, piped streams would be a good choice here - if not for reasons mentioned above.

Also, is starting that thread manually a good idea? What about using an ExecutorService instead?

Comment: Can this be a limit of the S3 object size? This article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/ notes a "old" object size limit of 5GB and a new limit (with multipart upload) of 5TB. Try to write the output stream to a file instead to AWS to test the limits of the implementation with a local output. (OK. Link is slightly old.) But test would show limit of stream or S3 implementation.

Comment: @Konrad sorry, I was not specific enough - it's not exactly about S3, i use this snippet of code for other storage providers(Azure etc.). File transfer actually works - but when it's done for the 5th time - the thread just hangs. Although, I appreciate the info you sent, it will come useful - thank you for that.

Comment: Did you create a thread dump of the VM to see the internal code locations of the threads while the thread is blocked. Next check the source to see what is expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal opinion about your design in the [mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117639/encrypting-large-streams-to-be-sent-via-amazon-s3). As you have mentioned, you are encrypting a **stream**, so I think that your encrypting method is not suitable.

In aforementioned thread, you are using `CBC` mode which in no way is suitable for stream ciphering. If what you are sending is really stream, I suggest to use stream ciphering modes such as `CTR` or stream cipher algorithms(even though former is advised).

If you use stream modes, you can encrypt/decrypt each part of content independently on the fly. So you may even be able to split your content and send your content in several parts rather than 1 big file. In addition, in streams modes, cipher text size is equal to plain text size, so you will know result size prior to encrypting.

**Regarding hanging threads**, I guess it may be because of encryption algorithm too. If you are using `AES/CBC/NoPadding` cipher as you posted on your thread, **you can only encrypt data which its size is multiple of `AES` block size** (16 bytes). This happens because you are using an block cipher mode without any padding mechanism. I guess your encryption should hang whenever your plain data(stream) size is not multiple of 16 bytes, not whenever size of data is very large. If this is really your problem, changing to stream cipher mode should solve this problem too.

Comment: Thanks for the input - i'll do some research then. But I assume this would not really fix the issue with hanging threads?

Comment: @user3285241 updated replay with a guess about hanging threads.

Comment: what if i was using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding instead?

Comment: by the way - the thread doesn't hang when i upload to S3, can't say that about Azure though.

Comment: @user3285241 if you are using that padding, it should be ok.